# how to use createdAt and updatedAt in sails js

Tags: sails.js

need a different time for createdAt and UpdatedAt time

I am using autoCreatedAt and autoUpdatedAt in sails Model..
when i create a data it stores created time in both the fields (created_at and updated_at).
when i update a data it stores updated time in both fields .
i need static time for both the fields when it get created (it should be created time). when i update it should not affect the created time.

```
created_at      : {type:'ref',columnType:'datetime',autoCreatedAt:true},
updated_at      : {type:'ref',columnType:'datetime',autoCreatedAt:true},
```

when created both the field get stored created time.
when updated both the field get stored updated time.

Comment: Double check your code... SHouldn't it be "autoUpdatedAt" instead? Wouldn't explain the behavior you are getting though...

Answer (score 0):

As per @Salketer comment, your code should be:

```
created_at      : {type:'ref',columnType:'datetime',autoCreatedAt:true},
updated_at      : {type:'ref',columnType:'datetime',autoUpdatedAt:true},
```

More info at [Sails Documentation](https://sailsjs.com/documentation/concepts/models-and-orm/model-settings#?attributes)